# use of ** in pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
main()
{
int a[]={5,4,3,2,1};
int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4 };
int **ptr=p;//what does it really means
cout<<a<<*a;/*prints the address of a, value of a[0] (i understand this line)*/
cout<<endl<<p<<*p<<**p;/*prints the address of p, address of a, value of a[0]    (understands this line's logic too)*/
cout<<endl<<ptr<<*ptr<<**ptr;\*this line's o/p is same as the previous one cant   understand why*/
}
```

please explain what is **ptr means and why the output of the third line same as the second line.

And one more doubt:

1. `int *ptr=(char *)0;`
2. `float *ptr=(float *)0;`
3. `char *ptr=(char *)0;`

i read in a article that these are all representations for a null pointer
 what is (char *) representing.

Comment: It means what it looks like. It's a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Comment: If you understand line 2, why not line 3?  Isn't it the same?

Comment: How not?  `p` decays into a pointer to its first element in those expressions, and `ptr` is a pointer to `p`'s first element.  That's the same where I come from.  I can't see how the case where it's a real pointer is harder to understand than the case where the array name is pulling tricks.

Comment: It's not the same. I don't know if it's "harder to understand".

Comment: @CarlNorum the type of `p` is not the same as that of `ptr` in C++, regardless of where one comes from.

Comment: What does that mean?  OP says he understands the line with `p`s in it, but the one with `ptr`s in it, right?  The types aren't meaningful in this case, since they are evaluated as if they were the same type.  There's no `sizeof` in there anywhere.  Besides, the types of `ptr` and of `&p[0]` *are* the same, and that's how they're used in this example.

Comment: Its really sad that you cant downvote juanchopanza and Elazar

Comment: Well I can write more comments that explain it, I guess...

Comment: @CarlNorum you can write the correct comment in the first place instead. There is much misunderstanding around pointers vs. arrays issue. Don't add to it.

Comment: @CarlNorum Your second comment is enough. The first one on its own is misleading.

Comment: @CarlNorum I think instead of being **raw** surprised, you should use `std::surprise` instead. `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays decay into pointers to their first elements in several contexts, including the expression contexts you're using them in there.  If we explictly use `&array[0]` rather than `array` by itself in a couple of those lines, maybe it will make more sense.  First, the declaration of `ptr`:

```
int **ptr = p;     // ptr is a pointer to the first element of p
int **ptr = &p[0]; //   and this expression is equivalent.
```

Next, the printing of `p` and friends - again, both expressions are the same.

```
cout << endl << p << *p << **p;
cout << endl << &p[0] << *&p[0] << **&p[0];
```

Now, the printing of the `ptr` line - since `ptr` is `&p[0]`, you can see that both of the lines are equivalent:

```
cout << endl << ptr << *ptr << **ptr;
cout << endl << &p[0] << *&p[0] << **&p[0];
```

And the second line there is identical to the second line just above - hence your identical output.

You might benefit from reading the [`comp.lang.c` FAQ section 6, Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
int **ptr=p
```

pointer to pointer to int

int *p[]  holds array of pointers ,address of int array a in your example.

The reason for the same output in your example.
**ptr and *p[0] ara same.
    **ptr == **(ptr +0) == *(*(p+0)) == **p  //all point to 0th element of array a.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html:

`
 Since we can have pointers to int , and
pointers to char, and pointers to any
structures we've defined, and in fact pointers
to any type in C, it shouldn't come as too
much of a surprise that we can have pointers
to other pointers. If we're used to thinking
about simple pointers, and to keeping clear in
our minds the distinction between the pointer
itself and what it points to , we should be able
to think about pointers to pointers, too,
although we'll now have to distinguish
between the pointer, what it points to, and
what the pointer that it points to points to.
(And, of course, we might also end up with
pointers to pointers to pointers, or pointers to
pointers to pointers to pointers, although
these rapidly become too esoteric to have any
practical use.)
The declaration of a pointer-to-pointer looks
like
int **ipp;
where the two asterisks indicate that two
levels of pointers are involved.
Starting off with the familiar, uninspiring,
kindergarten-style examples, we can
demonstrate the use of ipp by declaring some
pointers for it to point to and some int s for
those pointers to point to:

```
int i = 5, j = 6; k = 7;
int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;
```

Now we can set

```
ipp = &ip1;
```

and ipp points to ip1 which points to i. *ipp
is ip1 , and **ipp is i , or 5.

...

What are pointers to pointers good for, in
practice? One use is returning pointers from
functions, via pointer arguments rather than
as the formal return value. To explain this,
let's first step back and consider the case of
returning a simple type, such as int, from a
function via a pointer argument. If we write
the function

```
f(int *ip)
{
*ip = 5;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
int i;
f(&i);
```

then f will return'' the value 5 by writing it
to the location specified by the pointer passed
by the caller; in this case, to the caller's
variable i . A function might return'' values
in this way if it had multiple things to return,
since a function can only have one formal
return value (that is, it can only return one
value via the return statement.) The
important thing to notice is that for the
function to return a value of type int , it used
a parameter of type pointer-to- int.
Now, suppose that a function wants to return
a pointer in this way. The corresponding
parameter will then have to be a pointer to a
pointer. For example, here is a little function
which tries to allocate memory for a string of
length n , and which returns zero (false'') if
it fails and 1 (nonzero, or true'') if it
succeeds, returning the actual pointer to the
allocated memory via a pointer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int allocstr(int len, char **retptr)
{
char *p = malloc(len + 1); /* +1 for \0 */
if(p == NULL)
return 0;
*retptr = p;
return 1;
}
```

The caller can then do something like

```
char *string = "Hello, world!";
char *copystr;
if(allocstr(strlen(string), &copystr))
strcpy(copystr, string);
else fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
```

(This is a fairly crude example; the allocstr
function is not terribly useful. It would have
been just about as easy for the caller to call
malloc directly. A different, and more useful,
approach to writing a wrapper'' function
around malloc is exemplified by the
chkmalloc function we've been using.) 
`

Comment: This is beyond irrelevant

Comment: @Ulterior: It explains what **ptr means, doesn't it?